# Android FCM Push Notification Not Working When App is being Killed or Swipe Out from Recent Apps on One plus 3t Mobile

Tags: java, android, notifications, push

We are Developing an android app to receiveing a push notification from fcm we throughly tested the app in different mobiles all are working fine except oneplus 3t mobile. It Does not receive notification when app is being killed or swipe out from recent apps.It receives notification when app is in foreground or open.

We search lot of thing from internet lot of site says change the **notification** payload to **data** we are also change that it does not working in oneplus 3t mobile. And also give the android xml attribute

```
android:stopwithTask="false"
```

Nothing worked. Please give some solutions regarding this issue. In my point of view firebase messaging services also stopped when app is killed.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, on my OnePlus 3!

Answer (score 0):

Please check in mobile device is there any protected app feature or battery saver which stops the working of app in background. If allow the app to run in background from setting it will sort out your problem. I'm having honor 5x device which was having the same issue. To run the app in background I've added it in protected app list.

Comment: Thanks We Will Try it.